# Running mpi on multiple machines

Tags: ssh, mpi, distributed-computing, mpich

I can run my mpi program on a single machine with any number of processes, but cannot do it on multiple machines. I have a "machines" file, which specifies process counts on hosts as:

```
localhost:6
another_host:4
```

Below, I gave 3 examples:

```
// When I run the program on only localhost, everything is OK.
mpirun -n 10 ./myMpiProg parameter1 parameter2

// In this case, everything is OK, too.
mpirun -f machinesFile -n 10 ./myMpiProg parameter1 parameter2

// This is also OK
mpirun -n 8 ./myMpiProg parameter1 parameter2
```

When I changed machines file, like this:

```
localhost:6
another_host:2
```

...

```
// But this does not work.
mpirun -f machinesFile -n 8 ./myMpiProg parameter1 parameter2
```

The error below occurs when I ran the program in a distributed environment. More interesting, it always happens with some distributions: such as 8 processes, 12 processes. And it never happens with 10 processes.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what():  vector::reserve
```

So, is there any differences between running an mpi program on a single machine and multiple machines?

Comment: looks like it is something inside your code, not on the mpi side. Make sure that when you distribute the length of the vector to each of the processors, its length is correct.

Comment: Does it work when you replace `./myMpiProg ...` with something as simple as `hostname`?

Comment: > More interesting, it always happens with some distributions: such as 8 processes, 12 processes. And it never happens with 10 processes. 
That's your answer. Your code is written where you're using a vector of length 10. What I'd suggest is change your code to ensure it uses MPI_Comm_size() instead of a predefined value.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar I have already used MPI_Comm_size(). In fact, 10 is only a sample. It also runs with 4 or 6 processes.

Comment: @Sleepyhead It may be inside my code, as you said. I am checking my code now.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes it works with 'hostname' command. By the way, localhost can connect to another_host via ssh without password. But, the reverse is not true. Should I also configure another_host to connect to the localhost without password?

Comment: Do you mind posting a minimal code which has this error somewhere?

Comment: @Sleepyhead I tried to simplify the code, but encountered another problem. So, I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319156/boost-mpi-hangs-on Now I have a hanging on problem. After I could figure it out, I will update the question here and put the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem accidentally, but still do not know why. When I save isend requests in a vector, then everything is OK. But if I do not save them, the errors show up. It is sometimes std::length::error and sometimes longer as below.

The code that I can mention can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375285/2979477.
If I change this line:

```
mpiSendRequest.push_back(world.isend(neighbors[j], 100, *p));
```

as:

```
world.isend(neighbors[j], 100, *p);
```

the error shows up. It does not make sense to me, but maybe there is a reasonable explanation.

Error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::mpi::exception> >'
what():  MPI_Alloc_mem: Unable to allocate memory for MPI_Alloc_mem, error stack:
MPI_Alloc_mem(115): MPI_Alloc_mem(size=1600614252, MPI_INFO_NULL, baseptr=0x7fffbb499e90) failed
MPI_Alloc_mem(96).: Unable to allocate memory for MPI_Alloc_mem
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::mpi::exception> >'
what():  MPI_Alloc_mem: Unable to allocate memory for MPI_Alloc_mem, error stack:
MPI_Alloc_mem(115): MPI_Alloc_mem(size=1699946540, MPI_INFO_NULL, baseptr=0x7fffdad0ee10) failed
MPI_Alloc_mem(96).: Unable to allocate memory for MPI_Alloc_mem
[proxy:0:1@mpi_notebook] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:928): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:1@mpi_notebook] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:1@mpi_notebook] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:226): demux engine error waiting for event

=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 134
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)
```